# can i change pages url in ghost manually?

Tags: themes, ghost-blog

hello everybody i'm new to ghost and want to change page links for team page as example from :

www.myblog.com/team-name

to be like :

www.myblog.com/team/team-name

this is my routes.yaml page

routes:
  /team/: team
  /: home

collections:
  /blog/:
    permalink: /blog/{slug}/
    template:
    - index

taxonomies:
  tag: /topic/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/

and tried many solutions but nothing worked for me
any help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating team members as posts? If so something like this should do it:

```
collections:
  /:
    permalink: /{slug}/
    template: index
    filter: 'tag:-hash-team'
  /team/:
    permalink: /team/{slug}/
    template: team
    filter: 'tag:hash-team'
```

This will create a new posts collection appearing at "/team/". Any post tagged with the private tag "#team" will get put into this collection and appear as the link "/team/team-name/". No need for the initial team configuration under routes :). Hope this helps!